# MySQL select user who less performed an action

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structures:

```
ACTIONS

+  userid  +  action  +
+----------+----------+

USERS

+  id      +  name    +
+----------+----------+
+   1      + james    +
+----------+----------+
+   2      + john     +
+----------+----------+
```

A data example:

```
ACTIONS

+  userid  +  action  +
+----------+----------+
+   null   + action1  +
+----------+----------+
+   1      + action2  +
+----------+----------+
+   1      + action3  +
+----------+----------+
+   2      + action4  +
+----------+----------+
```

I need a SELECT query that will return the user who performed less actions.

If all fields are null (the first launch) or all equal (all users performed the same action), it can return 1 user (rand, asc, desc, it's the same).

///////////////////

**EDIT**

Based on the Richard Hamilton's reply, this query only works with users already in ACTIONS table. If one or more user_id are NULL or users are not in ACTIONS, doesn't select from USERS table

```
SELECT id FROM users
INNER JOIN actions ON users.id = actions.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(user_id)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: A sorted count against the ACTIONS table will produce your desired results.

Comment: could you please post the query?

Comment: What if there are two users with same amount of actions? like user 1 and 2 with 1 action each?

Comment: as specified, on equal users and number of actions, it returns 1 user (rand, asc, desc, it's the same).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `GROUP BY`. We can then `ORDER BY` the number of actions they performed.

To find the one with the lowest number, just use `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT user_id FROM users
INNER JOIN data ON users.id = data.users_id
GROUP BY action
ORDER BY COUNT(action)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That is a wrong answer given the OPs request. It is not counting the actions at all which is in another table.

Comment: I edited it again. Can you check if it works? And if not why not

Comment: It still won't work `sum(action)` will end in an error since action is a string.

Comment: OK then how about `count(action)`.

Comment: Your main table needs to be ACTIONS, based on OP's sample schema.

Comment: Added title to the example table. Actually my table contains all userid = NULL. I tried the query and returns 1 action instead of an user.

Comment: I specify that actions could be timestamps or whatever, the important is the userid counts

Comment: @RichardHamilton See the fiddle I created. Still not working. it is returning id 1 when it should be 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7baf6/1

Comment: replacing GROUP BY user_id and ORDER BY COUNT(user_id), which is almost correct, doesn't work if one or more user_id are null